# Compiler warning for statement on same line as #endif

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Consider code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 4;
#if 1
    printf("Hello world\n");
#endif a++;
    printf("a is %d\n", a);
}
```

Inadvertently, statement `a++;` is on the same line as a `#endif` and is not evaluated. As a result, the final output is:

```
Hello world
a is 4
```

On x86-64 clang 12, this is captured as a warning with using option `-Wextra-tokens`. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nzKq6sdrh).

I tried compiling this on Visual Studio 2019 MSVC, with command line options:

```
/JMC /permissive- /ifcOutput "Debug\" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"../include/" /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\windows.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

There is no warning of any sort on compilation. Is there a setting that can be passed to the compiler in MSVC that detects extra tokens?

---

Edited to add:

As answered by user [Nathan Pierson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12334309/nathan-pierson), it was indeed option `/Za` that worked. It does not seem to be on by default. I was also unable to use the Visual Studio Project Properties dialog to find out the option to set. Yet, one can feed in extra options manually thus:

[image]

---

ETA: Use of `/Za` is [not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's compiler warning [C4067](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4067?view=msvc-170). It looks like you need to set the flag `/Za` for it to apply to `#endif` directives.

In the Visual Studio properties page, this flag is controlled by the setting "Disable Language Extensions" in the Language subsection of the C/C++ section.

Comment: Use of `/Za` is [not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=msvc-170)